# Redirection Host

Tags: http, redirect, https, nginx-reverse-proxy

I own an app in the Google Playstore.

This is accessible under the following url:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=#APPID#

**#APPID# was used as a cover code.**

Now I wanted to redirect the default url to the playstore URL with my Nginx proxy manager.
Means: example.org => https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=#APPID#

I have now tried many settings.
Correct me if I am wrong but I have applied the following configuration:

- Domain Names: (example.org)
- Scheme: auto
- Forward Domain: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=#APPID#
- HTTP Code: 308
- Perserve Path: Yes
- Block COmmon Exploits: Yes.

And I add a SSL Certificate to my example.org

- Force SSL: Yes
- Everything else: No

it once (almost) worked and redirected me to https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=#APPID# **/**
(notice the / ) which is not recognized as url

Thanks in advance